# SQL select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am on SQL Server 2012, I am trying to write a `SELECT` statement that uses `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()` functions to display a `ProductName`  if the 3rd letter from the end of the product name is a particular letter.
Example the 3rd letter is an `'a'`

Comment: add data sample and expected results. Also, the query you need help with

Comment: SELECT ProductID, ProductName, UnitPrice, 
     LEFT(ProductName, LEN(ProductName) - 3)

Comment: Display ProductID, ProductName, and UnitPrice of products if the 3rd letter from the end of their ProductName is 'a' and have a unit price of $25 or higher. 
Solve this query by writing a SELECT statementSELECT that uses LEFT() and RIGHT() functions without LIKE.                                         This is as close as i could get                                                                SELECT ProductID, ProductName, UnitPrice,           
        LEFT(ProductName, LEN(ProductName) - 3)                       
FROM Products
WHERE UnitPrice >=25;

Comment: @F.Brown:you seem to be new here,I recommend going through below link (https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to know more on how to ask questions, you will get a faster response and in the long run it will help you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest optio here is to use `like`:

```
select ProductName from Products where ProductName like '%a__'
```

`%` is a wildcard matching any number of characters, and `_` matches a single characters. `like '%a__'` means the third-to-last letter is an `a`.
Working example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6b479/8

If you want to use `left` and `right`, you should use:

```
select ProductName from Products
where len(ProductName)>=3 AND left(right(ProductName,3),1)='a'
```

Working example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6b479/2

`left(right(ProductName,3),1)` means: take the last three letters, and take take the first letter out of them. We also check for `len(ProductName)>=3` to make sure there are at least three letters, otherwise we may return short product names that begin with an `a`.